# SQL Search + Join

Tags: sql

Need this question answered for SQL, would like some feedback. Bear with me, its been a while since ive used SQL. Is this correct?

Part 1: SQL
A database CriteoDB contains three tables: Product, User and Purchased.
Product contains:
• A unique identifier (productID)
• A name (productname)
• A price (productprice)
User contains:
• A unique identifier (userID)
Purchased contains:
• Two identifiers noted as private keys, productID anduserID
• A date of the record (creationdate)
Question:

1. Please write a query in SQL that will return a list of unique products that were bought on the
   retailer’s site since December 3rd with most expensive product returned first.

ANSWER:
a-To get all product id's bought since December 3rd:
SELECT productID FROM Purchased WHERE creationdate > 2020-12-03;

b-To get all products by descending price:
SELECT * FROM Product
ORDER BY ProductPrice DESC;

c-To join purchased and product table by ID:
SELECT *
FROM purchased
LEFT JOIN product
ON productID = purchasedID;

d-put it together:
SELECT productID FROM Purchased WHERE creationdate > 2020-12-03
LEFT JOIN product
ON productID = purchasedID
ORDER BY ProductPrice DESC;

Comment: If you actually execute the query, does it return the correct results? It seems to me this is a question you could answer yourself just by running the query and looking at the results.

Comment: This actually  looks pretty good.  You were not specific about which DB manager you're using and some are picky about keyword order.  Put your Where clause after the ON spec so you close out the From before beginning the Where.  Also date literals can be different in different DBs, if this one gives you trouble, insert the keyword DATE before 2020-12-03.